# What's the difference between passing parameter values using @ or wrapped in quotes to a component in Blazor C#?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I've been very confused about how to pass parameter values to C# Blazor components since there are several different syntaxes that are quite similar and I am unsure about when to use which.

For example, let's say there is a component

```
<MyButton />
```

that has a parameter property

```cs
[Parameter]
public string Label { get; set; }
```

What's the difference between

1. `<MyButton Label="Some Label" />`
2. `<MyButton Label=@someLabel />`
3. `<MyButton Label="@someLabel" />`
4. `<MyButton Label=someLabel />`
5. `<MyButton @bind-Label=@someLabel />`
6. `<MyButton @bind-Label="@someLabel" />`
7. `<MyButton @Label="Some Label" />`

Comment: It's just an evolutionary artifact: you were forced to use "@something", but they decided that the @ was redundant, and the quotes didn't make sense for non-string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Literals**: These are literal `string` values that are passed to the component as simple, static values. This is suitable if your label basically doesn't need to change but has a fixed value instead.
2. **Expressions**: Expression assign some local variable (in that case `someLabel` to the `Label` property. Essentially this means that if your `someLabel` variable changes, the component will rerender and the button label will update accordingly. Thus the Label property has a *dynamic* value. This is also called One-Way Binding.
3. **Quoted Expressions**: There is no difference between dynamic assignments with an `@` sign only or with additional quotes. Blazor allows dynamic assignments with and without quotation mark wrappers.
4. **Inferred Literals**: This might look like a variable assignment at first glance. However , Blazor actually infers this as a literal string since this syntax is valid in default html as well.
5. **Two-Way Binding**: Suppose there is a corresponding `[Parameter] EventCallback<T> LabelChanged` defined in `MyButton` this syntax Two-Way binds a variable `someLabel` to the component. This means that not only is `someLabel` dynamically assigned to the component label but also the other way around. A label is not a great use case for Two-Way-Binding but this behavior is neat indeed when working with inputs for example. 
    P. S.: It is necessary to follow the naming convention `{name of property}Changed` for the `EventCallback<T>` in order to make the binding work correctly.
6. **Quoted Two-Way Binding**: Again, Blazor doesn't care whether you wrap an assignment in quotes or not. Concluding this syntax equals 5. Two-Way-Binding.
7. **Directives**: Directives such as `@ref`, `@key`, or `@bind` bring additional functionality to a component. However, Blazor does not support custom directives (yet). The `Label` property won't be assigned to any value (I assume `null`) due to invalid markup syntax.

Comment: You don't make clear the different handling of strings and everything else.  `Label=someLabel` and `Label="someLabel"` will pass the literal `someLabel` where `Label` is a string.  For every other type `Value=someValue` or `Value="someValue"` where say Value is an `int` will pass the actual value of `someValue`.

Comment: What you also don't make clear is that these differences are in the way the the Razor compiler interprets the markup, not in the C# language and the way it compiles the code.  Relative beginners [and many others] too often miss this distinction.

Comment: Correct, thanks for elaborating. I know one could take this even further and talk about func expressions etc. I wanted to keep it as straight forward as possible. Please feel free to edit/extend my answer.

Answer (score 2):

While the description of all your 7 cases is correct, this is not the only way to categorize them.

### 1 Quotes

Razor is based on HTML and the recommended practice is to *always* use quotes around parameter values. And those quotes can be single (`'`) or double (`"`).
So, regardless of all other aspects, the following three notations are always the same:

a. `x=y`
b. `x='y'`
c. `x="y"`

The one exception here is that notation a) is only allowed when there are no spaces or other invalid chars in the value `y`.

### 2 prefix with `@`

The razor compiler knows the type of the parameter and will accept C# values here. The exception is with strings, `="someLabel"` and `=someLabel` assign literal text but in `="@someLabel"` it assigns the content of `string someLabel`.

#### Your examples

Cases 2) and 3) are exactly the same,

Cases 1) and 4) are the same , quotes are required for 1) because of the space.

Cases 5) and 6) are exactly the same again. And because the `@` is optional here (the Razor compiler knows you can't 2-way bind to literal text), the following two are the same as 5) and 6) as well:

8. `<MyButton @bind-Label='someLabel' />`
9. `<MyButton @bind-Label="someLabel" />`

#### From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#component-parameters):

> Quotes around parameter attribute values are optional in most cases per the HTML5 specification. For example, Value=this is supported, instead of Value="this". However, we recommend using quotes because it's easier to remember and widely adopted across web-based technologies.

and

> If the component parameter is of type string, then the attribute value is instead treated as a C# string literal by default. If you want to specify a C# expression instead, then use the @ prefix.

> We don't recommend the use of the @ prefix for literals (for example, boolean values), keywords (for example, this), or null, but you can choose to use them if you wish. For example, IsFixed="@true" is uncommon but supported.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a lot of programmers need rules to feel comfortable. The simple way to look at this is the @ breaks from html to C#. If you don't need quotes in C# don't use them. Blazor `.razor` files are a combination of C# and html.